# How to debug a broken site config on Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I am currently trying to run a simple BottlePY site on Apache2 but am getting an Internal Server Error.

Here is the config file for the site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin removed@removed.com
    ServerName removed.org
    DocumentRoot /sites/bottlepy

    # WSGI Settings
    WSGIScriptAlias / /sites/bottlepy/wsgi_handler.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess bottlepy user=sreustle group=general processes=1 threads=10
    WSGIProcessGroup bottlepy

    # Static Directories
    Alias /static /sites/bottlepy/static/
    <Location "/static">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is wsgi_handler.py

```
import os
import bottle

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

application = bottle.default_app()
```

It could be a few things going wrong, but I'm not sure how to debug apache. Could I get some suggestions on how to debug this? Thanks a lot!

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the bottom of my error log. [http://i.imgur.com/3CH3V.png](https://i.imgur.com/3CH3V.png)

Edit: Added updated wsgi_handler

Comment: Is there anything in /var/log/apache2/error.log?

Comment: You could take a 'black-box' approach and comment everything out.  Then start uncommenting things one at a time until you figure out what causes the problem.  Once you figure out what causes the problem, try and research that.

Comment: Error logs: http://i.imgur.com/3CH3V.png

wsgi_handler.py having trouble importing the bottle.py file in same dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottle package is not installed in the Python 2.6.5 installation that mod_wsgi is compiled against and which it is using.

Where did you install 'bottle'?

You either need to install it in Python 2.6.5 system wide site-packages directory, or ensure that any local Python packages directory or your own is setup in mod_wsgi configuration or your WSGI script file.

See the mod_wsgi documentation for further information:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques

Answer (score 0):

Check the Apache error log - I think it's in /etc/apache2/logs/error.log or /var/www/error.log on ubuntu by default but I'm not sure. That should tell you what's going on.